# What cameras can be used for custom street view? I mean lots of overlapping spherical panoramas which cover long distances

Tags: camera-recommendation, 360-panorama

Google Street View is good idea. But I don't know any way to make similar thing myself. Is there any?
What equipment would I need to make 1000 km of my own street view at once?

Comment: The question is a bit broad as it stands. Are you only asking about cameras, or the entire processing pipeline. 1000km of what, desert or Manhattan?

Comment: 1000 km of mostly highways.

Comment: webwalk might be of interest http://webwalk.com/demos.php (more indoor) but can be used for outside DIY streetview.

Comment: Related: [How are virtual tour photos taken?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8129/how-are-virtual-tour-photos-taken/49716#49716) and [Minimum requirements to capture a "Street View"-like photo](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56462/minimum-requirements-to-capture-a-street-view-like-photo)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, any decent digital camera could do the job, but the biggest challenge is to locate and orient the photos. Ideally, you should have a GNSS receiver for the position of the camera and an INS for its orientation (but you can deduce this from the street direction).

Furthermore, as you can see on [their site](http://www.google.com/maps/about/behind-the-scenes/streetview/), Google uses plenty of cameras in order to view in many directions at once.

Finally, you need a good storage on the computer that collect the photos.

Comment: The question is about 360 degrees camera array. How could this be made?

Comment: 360° view is made by merging individual photos together. Maybe I did not understand your question, but you did not mention 360 degrees arrays before. Please edit your question to add more details. For a 1000 km highway, I imagine that you can make realistic "street views" without building the 360 view (simply jump from one photo to the next)

Comment: OK. I edited the question to say that I mean spherical images. I think that synchronizing cameras at such velocity as 30 meters per second is a challenge. Same with setting steps in meters (not milliseconds). Another challenge is external storage. The storage must be sufficient to free me from constant stops to change it. If you can't drive more that 100 km without needing to replace the storage, I don't think you'd like it.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what kit you already have, or what your abilities are with respect to DIY rig making, or what your budget is, in order to "calibrate" your expectations, here are some things being made or are already on the market (as of September 2015).

Kickstarter projects for spherical cameras:

- [Sphericam](http://www.sphericam.com/) - This is a $2000 USD pre-order. (will go to $2500 after initial pre-order fulfillment, apparently)
- [Bublcam](http://www.bublcam.com/products/bublcam) - Also not on the market yet. I don't know the price, but making some assumptions based on the kickstarter levels, it looks like probably around $500-$700 USD.

Other solutions:

- PointGrey [Ladybug5](http://www.ptgrey.com/ladybug5-360-degree-usb3-spherical-camera-systems) - looks like more of a 'pro' or industrial solution. They don't list a price (they want you to contact them for the price). "If you have to ask..."
- GoPro has announced a [6-GoPro spherical rig](http://gopro.com/spherical). That's around $3000 USD just for the cameras alone, plus an unannounced price for the sphere (really, more like a rounded cube) rig.
- [Panano](https://www.panono.com/) is an interesting device: it has 36 cameras that combined take a 100 MP shot after *you throw it in the air* (it also can be triggered manually without having to throw it). It is supposed to ship from Germany in September 2015 for $1500 USD.
- Ricoh has the [Theta](https://theta360.com/en/), a small 2-camera device for around $250 at Amazon. Only takes up to 3 minute videos. But the small size and price could be compelling.

Comment: I have no Street View kit. 3 minute videos aren't OK at all. A trip takes hours. GoPro may give somewhat more but I don't think it could give about 1000 km.